# split-stake into derived account using --seed

Tags: solana-cli, stake

What is the proper syntax to split some active stake into a new stake account using the --seed flag? I have some ledger wallets I'd like to split stake out of one of the stake accounts and have the new stake account created/derived using the --seed flag all in one CLI command.

The help file says it's possible but fails to really give the proper layout of the command.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, I got it figured out. This command will split active stake into (and create) a derived stake account using a `--seed` for easy CREATION, and this uses a ledger wallet of a certain key index.

`solana split-stake <EXISTING STAKE ACCOUNT> usb://ledger?key=<INDEX#> <AMOUNT TO SPLIT> --keypair usb://ledger?key=<INDEX#> --seed <STRING>`